# Is there something wrong with the way that I'm setting up my methods?

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors

I keep getting an error about how java can not find my variable. I think I have an idea of my issue but do not how o go about it. I think there may be something wrong with the way I'm setting up my methods, or where I put my class Car. I'm not really sure and would like some help please.

This is my error:

2 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Nick\Car.java  [line: 37]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method FillUp()
  location: variable myBmw of type Car

File: C:\Users\Nick\Car.java  [line: 39]
Error: incompatible types
  required: int
  found:    void

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Car { //Nick
    static int gallonsintank;
    int mpg;
    public static void Fillup() {
        System.out.println("How many gallons?");
        Scanner fillhowmuch = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ifillhowmuch = fillhowmuch.nextInt();
        gallonsintank = gallonsintank + ifillhowmuch;
    }
    public static void Taketrip()  {
         System.out.println("How many miles?");
         Scanner howmanymiles = new Scanner(System.in);
         int ihowmanymiles = howmanymiles.nextInt();
         int mpg = ihowmanymiles / 5;
         gallonsintank = gallonsintank - mpg;
    }
    public static void ReportFuel()  {
        System.out.println(gallonsintank);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])  {
         Car myBmw = new Car();  
         myBmw.FillUp();  
         myBmw.Taketrip();  
         int gallonsintank = myBmw.ReportFuel();  
         System.out.println(gallonsintank);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want help with a compiler error, it is very helpful to include the actual compiler error

Comment: At least one error is that `ReportFuel` returns void and you are trying to assign an int (gallonsintank) to it in your main method. What variable is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: And identify the lines flagged.

Comment: -1 for failing to include the error messages (initially) and then failing to identify what lines they referred to.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

1. myBmw.FillUp();
   is a type error, the method name is declared as `Fillup` and in main you use `FillUp`
2. the ReportFuel is not returning an int, as you want in main()

   public static void Fill`u`p()
   {
   ...
   }

   public static `void` ReportFuel()
   {
   ...
   }

**in main you do:**

`myBmw.FillUp();`
Which is wrong spelled, it should be `myBmw.Fillup();`

and in main you do:
`int gallonsintank = myBmw.ReportFuel();`

But ReportFuel is returning nothing in Car class (void declared!)